# The meaning of それを昨日、今日、司教になったようなのが！

Tags: grammar, meaning

Context: This old man, one of the candidates to become the new pope, had one of his subordinates secretly check how the various churches had voted for who they want to be pope, and he noticed that the large majority voted for another person(who has been in the church for a much shorter time than him but not that short). He then complains to this person as follows:

> 儂が何年司教を続けたと思っている！　ひゃ、１００年！　１００年だ！　それを昨日、今日、司教になったようなのが！

My question is about what he means in the second part. Is he complaining that they are treating his 100 years of dedication to the church as if he had only became a bishop very recently?

Edit: From l'électeur's answer I now understand the end part of the sentence, but the first part where he says それを is confusing me as I, in gist, can't determine what he means by it as the accompanying verb isn't said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not what it means.  This is a fairly advanced question.

> 「それを[昨日]{きのう}、[今日]{きょう}、[司教]{しきょう}になったような**の**が！」

This phrase is about the other person with less experience, not about the speaker.

**Two things that I think you are missing**:

1) This is not a sentence; The entire predicate is being left unsaid.  It is only implied.  (This is why it ends with 「が」)

2) 「の」 is a nominalizer, and it refers to a "***person***" here.  Specifically, it is the other person with less experience than the speaker.

「昨日今日」 is a common set phrase meaning "just recently".

So what is being left unsaid?

It would be along the lines of 「[儂]{わし}より[先]{さき}に[法王]{ほうおう}になりやがって！」 = "has become the Pope before I have!"

Put it altogether, you have:

***"A guy who became a bishop just recently has now become the Pope before I have!"***

Comment: Ah I see, I had determined that it would be one of those two out context(and so I included the difference in experience between them). I had thought that the の might have been replacing a different word such as 扱い. My only problem is that I don't see what それを is then referring to

Comment: I should probably add this as I accidentally made it a bit misleading. These votes themselves aren't the sole determinant for who does become the new pope. After he says the line mentioned he then says 次の法王になるのは、儂！　儂！

Comment: @chiken The それを means それなのに, "despite that".