# Understanding それをこいつは

Tags: grammar

> 死神の異名を持つ同い年のその戦隊長は、それまでのライデンの経験からは信じられないほど杜撰で気まぐれだった。
>
> 哨戒の類は一切させず、どこに〈レギオン〉が潜んでいるとも知れぬ廃墟を一人で探索し、レーダーに何の反応もないうちから突然出撃命令を出す。それらは確かに気味が悪いほどそのとおりだったけれど、ライデンにしてみれば自殺志願者としか思えない無防備さだった。
>
> 腹に据えかねた。
>
> 一緒に入隊した友人達はみんな死んだけれど、それまで必死で戦った。あの老婦人は撃たれるかもしれないのに、それでも必死にライデン達を守ろうとした。
>
> **それをこいつは**。まるで誰が死んでも、自分が死んでも構わないと思っているかのように。

86─エイティシックス─

How should I understand the bold part? What is omitted there?

Comment: Related: Chocolate's comment [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23900/5010).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not fully sure on this, but I believe the full stop is what's throwing you off. それを [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%82%92-2057944) essentially means それなのに, and こいつは is directly connected to what's in the next sentence.

'But despite that, this person... They almost seem like they don't care who dies, not even themselves.'